# Composite Deck Surface Mount Post Bracket

Tags: deck

I noticed that for wood decks, there are surface mount deck brackets for the 4 x 4 posts.  I just resurfaced my wood deck with composite.  I have been unable to find those brackets for composite deck material.  Are there surface deck mount posts for composite?

[link to the wood version](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Veranda-Surface-Mount-Bracket-and-Post-Kit-BKT-SLV-MT-W-WD-KT-V/202353463)

Comment: Why do they need to be different? Do your new posts have different dimensions?

Comment: No, they are 4x4.  I have never worked with composite material before.  It seems to be more pliable than wood.  I was scared that it wouldn't be as rigid.

Answer (score 1):

These brackets will also work for composite material. The composite material might be harder on a cheap drill bit, but so long as you can drill a hole through the deck, you can mount a bracket to it.